# Vectorizing for loops in python when read some images

Tags: python, python-3.x, vectorization

I'm new in python and i wrote a code to read some images in 2 `for Loops` and compute some values and then added them into a dictionary but because of huge number of images , it doesn't efficient at all. I want to help me for vectorizing this code . Thanks

```
Testimages = [f for f in glob(f'{test_dir}/*.jpg')] 
MinDist = float('inf')
test_dictionary = dict()
for img_tst in tqdm(Testimages):

 imgTensor_test = ImageLoader(img_tst)
 imgTensor_test = to_var(imgTensor_test)
 embed_vector_test = model.cnn(imgTensor_test)
 for img_fname in tqdm(images):

   basename = os.path.basename(img_fname)
   foldername = basename.split('.')[-2]
   dist = float(np.linalg.norm(embed_vector_test.data.cpu().numpy() - load_array('datalab/whale/train_vector/'+foldername))) 
   if dist < MinDist :
     MinDist = dist
     label = img_fname.split('/')[-2] //end second loop

 basename_test = os.path.basename(img_tst)   
 test_dictionary[basename_test]=label //end first loop
```

Comment: Check out numpy.vectorize (I think that's what it was called)

Comment: The time cost of your for loops are negligible, don't bother. If it's slow it's because of other factors.

Comment: first loop has 15000 image and second one 9800 img , each iteration in second loop has 3 second length. so it doesn't good anymore!